# Remove Blue Toolbar from MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, plot

A MATLAB figure outputs a blue toolbar around the image. 
I need to remove the blue toolbar.

I was using:

```
figure('Toolbar','none')
```

but it removes the menubar but not the blue toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this what you meant, but I believe you wanted to "maximize" the plot to fill the entire figure.

Example:

```
plot(cumsum(rand(1000,1)-0.5))   %# some plot
set(gca, 'Position',[0 0 1 1])   %# maximize axis plotting area
set(gcf, 'Menubar','none')       %# remove menubar
```

optionally also hide the tick marks:

```
set(gca, 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[])
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You have it the other way around, I think you want to remove the menubar (not just the toolbar):

```
figure('MenuBar','none')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But when I use either: figure('Toolbar','none','Menubar','none'), it removes the bar underneath and not the blue toolbar.

Comment: What blue toolbar? Please realize that everyone has a different layout and may not have this "blue toolbar" you are referring to/